# STM32: Reading temperature data from the BMP388 sensor

Tags: stm32, i2c, stm32cubeide

I started working with STM32 last week. So I am new to coding with the STM32CubeIDE. I am trying to read the temperature data from the BMP388 sensor and then show me in the debugger call. I have created the following code and try to read the registers from the data sheet of the sensor. I have created the following code and use the HAL_I2C_Mem_Read function. When I try to get the Data from the Live Expressions of the Debugger, I receive a Value of *2394.*

This is my code:

I defined the register as followed:

```
#define SLAVE_ADDRESS    0x76       // READ ADDRESS
#define CONTROLL     0x08       // Register Address for Controlling
#define TEMPERATURE_DATA 0x22
```

Then created variables to store the Data in:

```
  uint8_t i2c_rx_buffer[3];
  uint8_t i2c_write;
  float temperature;
```

In the while(1)-loop I call the *HAL_I2C_Mem_Read*.

```
  while (1)
  {
      i2c_write = CONTROLL;
      // CHECK-Bedingung
    if(HAL_I2C_IsDeviceReady(&hi2c1, SLAVE_ADDRESS << 1, 1, HAL_MAX_DELAY) == HAL_OK){
          HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LED_LD3_GPIO_Port, LED_LD3_Pin, SET);
    }

     // I2C read, first need to write to the Register for control Byte --> CONTROLL 
     HAL_I2C_Mem_Write(&hi2c1, SLAVE_ADDRESS << 0, CONTROLL, I2C_MEMADD_SIZE_8BIT, &i2c_write, 1, 1000);
     // Read the Data from the SLAVE Device and stores it in the value i2c_rx_buffer with the size of a 3 Byte
     HAL_I2C_Mem_Read(&hi2c1, SLAVE_ADDRESS << 1, TEMPERATURE_DATA , 3, i2c_rx_buffer, 3, 1000);

     // stores the data of all three byte values in one!
     temperature = (float)(((int32_t)i2c_rx_buffer[2] << 16) | ((int32_t)i2c_rx_buffer[1] << 8) | (int32_t)i2c_rx_buffer[0]);

     float celsius = ((float)temperature - 32) * 5/9;
     HAL_Delay(1000);

}
```

Used this Datasheet: https://www.alldatasheet.com/view.jsp?Searchword=Bmp388&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIzZzGoYem_QIVCYbVCh2ulABcEAAYAiAAEgJTEvD_BwE

I don't know what I am doing wrong.

I use the STM32F303VCT6 Discovery Board. And use the I2C Pins PB7 = SDA and PB6 = SCL. I Connected the Sensor and grounded the SD0 Pin on the sensor like mentioned in the Datasheet.

I get values that cannot be correct.

Comment: At the very least, this seems wrong: `SLAVE_ADDRESS << 0`. It should be shifted left by one bit.

Comment: I don't see a register called `CONTROLL` or anything similar in the datasheet at offset `0x08`. Nor any register at `0x22`.

Comment: @pmacfarlane so i shift the SLAV_ADDRESS by one Bit. 
How can I find the register of the Temperature? I only found that the data of the temperature is stored in the register 0x07 to 0x09. And it sores in DATA_3 to DATA_5. 
It stores an 24Bit temperature and this Bits are split and stores in a register. How can should I use the register then?

Comment: @pmacfarlane could you exlain what the register of the Temperature would be?

Comment: As you said, it seems to be registers `0x07` to `0x09`.

Comment: @pmacfarlane, when I would like to read or receive the Data from these three registers, do I have to use **three receive/read Commands?** 
And when I want to combine them then, I should do it like this:
`temperature = (float)(((int32_t)i2c_rx_buffer[2] << 16) | ((int32_t)i2c_rx_buffer[1] << 8) | (int32_t)i2c_rx_buffer[0]);`


Right?